# creating file and folder loop

Tags: python, linux

Hey there I tried making a loop for creating folders and files. 
According to me the program should work like this :

1. create 1st folder and 1 file inside it.
2. create 2nd folder and 1 file inside it

and it goes on.....
What my program does is :

1. create 1 file
2. create folders

my program

```
import os,sys

di=("ab")
a=0
i=0
fi=open("az.txt","w")

def file():
    for i in range(0,10):
        fi.write(str(i))

def mk():
    for a in range(0,10):
        os.mkdir(di+str(a))
        file()

mk()
```

please help

Comment: Simple debugging: put `print` statements inside the various loops (make their strings unique) and follow the flow of the program.

Comment: NB: `file` is a built-in Python function. You're overriding it, so you'll be using your function, but better rename it, to something like `create_files`.

Comment: @Torxed the content of az.txt is the valuse of i

Comment: @Evert thanks
I did change the function but it had no effect the file is still being created outside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will create a folders with the name "a", "b", "c" and put files  1.txt 2.txt .. 5.txt in each folder.

Make a changes as you need as try it.

```
import os
for i in "abc":
    os.system ("mkdir "+i)
    for j in range (5):
            os.system ("touch "+str(i)+"/"+str(j)+".txt")
```

Comment: thanks it worked :)
but can you please explain me how it works

Comment: which statement you want to know? os.system - is running bash command in terminal.
When you comabine "mkdir "+i - actualy you run command "mkdir a"
after that  you  build and run bash command to create a file "touch a/1.txt"
Basic bash commands

Comment: if you need to put some content in some file - just put in right position the command : os.system("echo blabla > somefile.txt") OR if the content is known and the name of the file is known : os.system("echo "+content+" > "+filename).Please make sure you have spaces on right place while building the command

Answer (score 1):

> *Hey there I tried making a loop for creating folders and files. According to me the program should work like this : 1) create 1st folder and 1 file inside it. 2) create 2nd folder and 1 file inside it and it goes on..... What my program does is : 1) create 1 file 2) create folders*

Indeed, it does the latter and not the former. What your program does is create directories, and write:

```
0123456789
```

ten times inside `az.txt`. Your error is that you're opening a file outside of any loop, and then you write to it within a loop.

I guess, that's what you want:

import os,sys

```
di="ab"

def mk_file(di):
    for i in range(0,10):
        with open("{}/az_{}.txt".format(di,i), "w") as fi:
            fi.write(str(i))

def mk_dir():
    for a in range(0,10):
        dname = "{}_{}".format(di, str(a))
        os.mkdir(dname)
        mk_file(dname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mk_dir()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but your program does the same thing it creates the files outside the folder 
I wanted the files to be created inside the folder

Comment: sorry, forgot a detail: it's to open the file within the folder :-) Corrected in last edit.

Comment: yup, I was'nt giving the name used to create the file in `mk_file`. Sorry again. This time I tested the code and it works.